# pandas groupby to list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

this is my data:

```
data = [
 {'shape': 'circle', 'width': 10, 'height': 8},
 {'shape': 'circle', 'width': 7, 'height': 2},
 {'shape': 'square', 'width': 4, 'height': 6}
]
```

I am trying to group by shapes that will hold the x, y

my final output should be a dict in the following format:

```
{
 'circle': [
   {'x': 10, 'y': 8}, 
   {'x': 7, 'y': 2}
 ],
 'square': [
   {'x': 4, 'y': 6}
  ],
}
```

here is what I tried, which does not work

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.rename({'width': 'x', 'height': 'y'}, axis='columns')
df.groupby('shape').apply(
            lambda s: s.do_dict()).to_dict()
```

what is the correct way to do it? also is there a way to do it with out renaming the columns before, something like:

```
df.groupby('shape').apply(
   lambda s: {'x': s['width'], 'y': s['height']}).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not do without renaming the column but something like this?

```
(df.rename(columns={'width': 'x', 'height': 'y'})
    .groupby('shape')
    .apply(lambda s: s[['x', 'y']].to_dict(orient='records'))
    .to_dict())
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a dict comprehension:

```
res = {i:df[df['shape']==i][['x', 'y']].to_dict(orient='records') for i in set(df['shape'])}

>>>print(res)
{'circle': [{'x': 10, 'y': 8}, {'x': 7, 'y': 2}], 'square': [{'x': 4, 'y': 6}]}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid using a for loop